# How to print the array values combined with two arrays using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have loaded two array collection  "Array Collection A"  and "Array Collection B". I want to compare the array key value paris from two arrays. I have mentioned the output array result format. please help us. How to do it.

```
foreach($rec_res as $key => $itemA)
{
    $match=0;

    foreach($domain_result as $itemB)
    {
        if($itemA["item_id"]==$itemB["item_id"] && $itemA["order_id"]==$itemB["order_id"])
        {
           if( !in_array($itemB["domain_name"],$activated) && isset($itemB["license_id"]) ) 
           {
            $rec_res[$key]["domain_name"]=$itemB["domain_name"];
            $rec_res[$key]["activation_key"]=$itemB["activation_key"];
            $rec_res[$key]["license_id"]=$itemB["license_id"];
            $rec_res[$key]["active_license"]=$itemB["active_license"];
            $rec_res[$key]["dm_item_id"]=$itemB["item_id"];

            $match=1;
            $activated[] = $itemB["domain_name"];
            break;
        }
    }
    if($match==0)
    {
            $rec_res[$key]["domain_name"]="";
            $rec_res[$key]["activation_key"]="";
            $rec_res[$key]["license_id"]="";
            $rec_res[$key]["active_license"]="";
            $rec_res[$key]["dm_item_id"]="";


    }
}
```

**Array Collection A:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 3

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2

        )

)
```

**Array Collection B:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [license_id]=>1
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2
            [domain_name]=> www.yahoo.com


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [license_id]=>2
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 3
            [domain_name]=> www.yahoo.com


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
           [license_id]=>3
           [item_id] => 229
           [product_id] => 2
           [domain_name]=> www.google.com

        )
)
```

**Output:**

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2
            [license_id]=> 1
            [domain_name]=> www.yahoo.com

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 3
            [license_id]=> 2
            [domain_name]=> www.yahoo.com


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2
            [license_id]=> 3
            [domain_name]=> www.google.com

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 229
            [product_id] => 2
            [license_id]=> 
            [domain_name]=> 


        )

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't spontaneously spot the difference between the second and third arrays and don't know how the first array relates to both. Please explain more clearly!

Comment: Hi deceze, i have edited the content. Please look on it

Comment: @ahalya: Are you getting this from a database? You may want to use JOIN so that MySQL does that for you!

Comment: No. This is for a static.

Comment: Yeah, just changing a word doesn't make it any clearer. Please express the necessary merging algorithm in words. While you're at it, writing it in code shouldn't be too hard then.

Comment: i have mentiond the code did

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate. You need to merge by keys.

[Merge 2 arrays and combine results of numerical keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856276/merge-2-arrays-and-combine-results-of-numerical-keys/16856652#comment24311309_16856652).

As Madara mentioned, if this comes from a database move the computing cost over to that by using a join query.