# Merge 2 arrays and combine results of numerical keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays in which I wish to merge/group together by each numerical key. 
eg

```
Array1
(
    [2009] => 131
    [2008] => 940
    [2007] => 176
    [2006] => 1
)
Array2
(
    [2008] => 9
    [2007] => 3
)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Array (
    [2009] => 131
    [2008] => Array (
                     [0]=>940
                     [1]=>9
                    )
    [2007] => Array (
                     [0]=>176
                     [1]=>3
                    )
    [2006] => 1
)
```

How on earth do I achieve this? I have tried array_merge but I lose my keys and they don't get grouped.

Comment: you probably would have to write your own function for this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this function that helped me. Thank you everyone for your input.

```
function merge_common_keys()
{
    $arr  = func_get_args();
    $num  = func_num_args();
    $keys = array();
    $i    = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; ++$i) {
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
    }
    $keys   = array_unique($keys);
    $merged = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $merged[$key] = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; ++$i) {
            $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key]) ? $arr[$i][$key] : null;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I see that right you only want those key to hold an array, that reference *more* than a single value. The other keys should still refer to scalar values...

So you need a two step strategy:

```
// 1.) turn _all keys into arrays
foreach (array($input1,$input2) as $array)
    foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val)
        $output[$key][]=$val;
// 2.) reconvert elements with single entry to a scalar value again
foreach ($output as $key=>$candidate)
    if (1==count($candidate))
        $output[$key]=$candidate[0];
// test output
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write a method to merge them?

```
/**
Merge original_array with new_array
@param array original_array
@param array new_array
*/
function merge_array($original_array, $new_array)
{
    $merged_array = array();
    if(is_array($original_array) && is_array($new_array))
    {
        foreach($original_array as $key => $value)
        {
            $merged_row[] = $value;
            if(isset($new_array[$key]))
            {
                $merged_row[] = $new_array[$key];
            }
            $merged_array[$key] = $merged_row;
        }
    } else $merged_array = $original_array;
    return $merged_array;
}
```

Comment: You can skip the first if-statement by changing the function header to:
    function merge_array(array $original_array, array $new_array)

Comment: You welcome. This only works with arrays and object names to force a parameter to be of that type. This won't go for ints, strings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just unit tested this. It should union the arrays. Mind you it could be improved in terms of performance. Items *without* an associative key will be grouped into key '0'.

```
   public function merge(&$ar, $ar2) {
      foreach ($ar as $k => $v) {
         if (isset($ar2[$k])) {
            $ar[$k] = array_merge(array($ar[$k]), array($ar2[$k]));
         }
      }

      foreach ($ar2 as $k => $v) {
         if (!isset($ar[$k])) {
            $ar[$k] = $ar2[$k];
         }
      }    
    }
```

The unit test:

```
public static function test_merge() {
      $ar1 = array(45, 'a' => 44, 'dog' => array(1), 'cat' => 3);
      s($ar1, array(2, 'dog' => 2, 'cat' => 4, 'stuff' => 4.3));
      print_r($ar1);
}
```

The result:

```
IArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 2
        )

    [a] => 44
    [dog] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [1] => 2
        )

    [cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [stuff] => 4.3
)
```

Comment: An ideal solution would be to use func_get_args() so the method could take a series of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arrOne = array( 2009 => 131,  2008 => 940,  2007 => 176,  2006 => 1);
$arrTwo = array( 2008 => 9, 2007=> 3, 2011 => 67);
$output = array();


foreach($arrOne as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($arrTwo[$key])){
    $output[$key][] = $value;
    $output[$key][] = $arrTwo[$key];
  }
  else{
    $output[$key] = $value;
  }
}

$output += $arrTwo;    // To consider keys that were absent in $arrOne 
print_r($output);

?>
```

Check the output in http://codepad.org/FrIlKRqk

And the result

```
Array
(
[2009] => 131
[2008] => Array
    (
        [0] => 940
        [1] => 9
    )

[2007] => Array
    (
        [0] => 176
        [1] => 3
    )

[2006] => 1
[2011] => 67
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays use the same keys, so you could do something simple like this (only works on one level though):

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    $array1[$key][] = $value
}
```

**Update:**

```
$array3 = array()
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $array3[$key][] = $value
}
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    $array3[$key][] = $value
}
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed I wrote this based on the idea that your first variable already used arrays for each year. So this won't work with your current situation. I'll keep the answer just for reference.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work without parentheses. I'm so stuck in Python atm I have forgotten PHP needs them :p (edited the code)

Comment: Haha it's okay ;) also your idea was not possible because you can't have the same keys in an array.

Comment: So either friday afternoon's playing up, or I'm not using duplicate keys?

Comment: I blame the friday afternoon, and in PHP there is no such thing as duplicate keys. if there was, you could expect a lot of horror. because how do you want to implement that? `array_addkey`?

Comment: Well, naturally you would run into trouble if you use one key twice or more... however, in my code I was adding a value to an array with the key `$key`, which can't create duplicate keys.

Comment: I see here a possiblity change `$array1[$key][] = $value` to `$array1[$key] = array_merge($value,(array)$array1[$key])` :)

Answer (score 0):

probaly something like that? If you run such a loop for each Array (array1, array2,…)

```
$list = array()

foreach( $array1 as $key => $value ){
    if( !array_key_exist( $key, $array) ){
        $list[$key] = $value
    } else if( !is_array( $list[$key] ) ) {
        $list[$key] = array(list[$key])
    } else {
        array_push( $list[$key], $value );
    }
}
```

nb.: the code is not tested…

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value)
    $array_new[$key][] = $value;
print_r($array_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see much answers but I dont find them usable so Im adding my own

```
function merge(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $new = array();
    foreach($args as $arg){
        foreach($arg as $key => $item){
            if(!isset($new[$key])){
                $new[$key] = $item;
            }else if (!is_array($new[$key)){
                $new[$key] = array($new[$key],$item);
            }else{
                $new[$key][] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

You can put in unlimited arguments :)